# Change the reclassify method in reclassify tool in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, reclassify

I'm trying to get use to ArcGIS Pro and I have tried the reclassify tool.
The thing is that I know that in ArcMap there is an option to see histogram of the raster values and also choose the classify method (e.g equal count etc) but I can't find this option in the Pro.

[image]

Is there any method to see the histogram and change the reclassification method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is currently no, get yourself over to GeoNet Ideas and [vote on it](https://community.esri.com/ideas/14816-reclassify-rasters-in-arcgis-pro)!